# Parsing variables into Get-ADUser CMDLT - Error parsing query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to write some scripts to match a partial AD user account name into a get-aduser script to return the objects for another routine.

However, the command when executed it returning a parse error

The strange thing is that when checking the syntax of the output, it looks AOK:

> PS C:\Users> **$ADUserString** = "dcro"
>
> PS C:\Users> **write-host get-aduser** -filter "{SAMAccountName -like '"$ADUserString*'"}"
>
> get-aduser -filter {SAMAccountName -like "dcro*"}

Note: I have used the right-tick character ` prepeding the quotes on the variable to keep them as a string value

So when executing the command:

> PS C:\Users> get-aduser -filter "{SAMAccountName -like `"$ADUserString*`"}"
>
> *get-aduser : **Error parsing query:** '{SAMAccountName -like "dcro*"}' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + get-aduser -filter "{SAMAccountName -like `"$ADUserString*`"}"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: '{SAMAccountName -like "dcro*"}' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser*

However, if I manually type the output from my 'write-host' above, it executes perfectly fine and returns the results I am after:

> PS C:\Users> get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -like "dcro*"}
>
> DistinguishedName : CN=Dan*****,OU=A*****port,OU=Development*****************
>
> Enabled           : True
>
> GivenName         : D****
>
> Name              : D*****Cro****
>
> ObjectClass       : user
>
> ObjectGUID        : 796b**********413-558d*****d73
>
> SamAccountName    : dcro*****
>
> SID               : S-1******************67
>
> Surname           : Cro******
>
> UserPrincipalName : dcro***********

It's pretty odd, and my feeling is that there are some weird special characters at play here.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```powershell
$ADUserString = "dcro*"
write-host (Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $ADUserString} | Out-String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround I found was this (not so pretty).

```
$ADUserString = "dcro"
$AdUserStringWildCard = "$AdUserString*"
Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $AdUserStringWildCard}
```

Have you tried LDAPFilter anr instead?  I know it tends to be iffy but might work in your scenario.  It seems good at completing usernames.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$ADUserString)"
```